Issue with AWS SDK for Java v2 (S3) Connection on macOS
I'm encountering an issue with the AWS SDK for Java v2 specifically for S3, but only on one particular Mac computer. The same code works fine on other machines (both Mac and Ubuntu). Interestingly, the AWS SDK v1 works perfectly on this problematic Mac, as does the AWS CLI.
Here's a snippet of the Java code I'm using:
String accessKeyId = “<my-access-key>;
String secretAccessKey = "<my-secret-access-key>”;

String bucketName = "activate-datafeed";
String prefix = "work_area/";

// Create AWS credentials
AwsBasicCredentials awsCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);

// Create the S3 client
S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
    .region(Region.US_EAST_1) // Replace with your bucket's region
    .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
    .build();

try {
    // List objects in the specified bucket and prefix
    ListObjectsV2Request listObjectsReqManual = ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .prefix(prefix)
        .build();

    ListObjectsV2Response listObjResponse = s3.listObjectsV2(listObjectsReqManual);
    // Process response...
} catch (S3Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Here’s my Maven dependency:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.26.14</version> <!-- Use the latest stable version -->
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

The Issue:
On the problematic Mac, I receive the following stack trace:
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: null) 
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(...) 
... 
at    software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(...) 
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(...) 
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.listObjectsV2(DefaultS3Client.java:6430) 
at com.example.s3.S3ListObjects.main(S3ListObjects.java:39)

What I've Tried:
•   The connection works on other machines, so it's likely specific to this particular Mac.
•   AWS SDK v1 works fine on this Mac, as does the AWS CLI.
•   I've confirmed that the region, bucket name, and credentials are correct.

What Could Be the Issue?
I'm wondering if there's something specific to the environment on this Mac that's causing the problem with AWS SDK v2. Could it be related to the Java installation, network configuration, or something else?
Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!

I was surprised to see that this question was marked as "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." I believe I provided detailed information about the issue, including relevant code snippets, the environment specifics, and the error messages. Could anyone clarify what might be unclear or how I can improve the question to make it more useful?

Do you have SDK debug logs available?

Check your POM. If you have this:
  <dependency>
       <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
       <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
       <version>2.26.14</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>

You do not need to specify a version here:
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version> 
</dependency>

Having a mismatch between the versions of the AWS SDK BOM (Bill of Materials) and the individual service dependencies can lead to runtime errors. A version mismatch can indeed cause issues, such as the S3Exception you're encountering

New dependencies: 
software.amazon.awssdk
bom
2.26.14
pom
import



software.amazon.awssdk
s3

Gives the error: Could not find artifact software.amazon.awssdk:s3:jar:unknown in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

check against  -- https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/pom.xml

Compilation works fine, thank you! But the error is the same

Make sure the pom looks like
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.26.14</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


Yes, it is my pom now, exactly, did not help

After you updated yourt POM - is code working?

Yes, the code works fine, still the same error in connection just on one computer
